# How to connect godot with MS SQL server instance?

Tags: c#, sql-server, godot

I am using godot mono with c# support, and trying to connect to a remote MS SQL server. I'm not even sure is it possible to do it directly, but if it is please tell me how.

I imported `System.Data.SqlClient` witch would be enough for any ordinary windows app in c#.

```
using Godot;
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net;


public class Node2D : Godot.Node2D
{
    public override void _Ready()
    {
        SqlConnection con = null;
        string constr = "server=0.0.0.0;database=blabla;uid=blabla;pwd=blabla";
        con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        con.Open();
        GD.Print(con.State.ToString());
    }
}
```

The program breaks on `con.Open()` and this is what i get:

> Socket error: 10054

[image]

I also got a debugger error saying that authentication or decryption has failed.

Comment: Can you connect using those details from within sql server management studio? That looks like standard C# I don't know that Godot has any bearing here.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to mention you are doing this on Linux? is that the case?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid if i enter correct ones i can. But I can't share those

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid no, it's windows 10

Comment: hmmm OK. That's not a SQL Server error message I've ever seen.

Comment: If you're on windows, why does the error say "unix"?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: 10054 is `WSAECONNRESET`, "An existing connection was forcibly closed by a remote host", which is a low-level TCP/IP error that doesn't tell you much. This comes from the Mono implementation of the `SqlClient`/socket library implementation. Verify that you can connect to the server with less adventurous code (i.e. try a normal .NET/.NET Core application) or `sqlcmd`; if you can, the issue may be that the Mono being used is too old/buggy in its TDS code with an SQL Server that's too new.

Comment: So basically as per my first comment: try some basic connectivity tests first. I don't believe Godot is relevant here at all.

Comment: i already tried. A simple c# windows form app was able to connect.

Comment: So what's the difference between this app and your basic C# app?

Comment: The same code run in C# app written in visual studio and this one in godot have different effect. First one runs smoothly, this one throw an error.